# rebuild a vmware machine in KVM with an .ova file

Tags: vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization

I want to run vmware PKS in a KVM virtual machine and have the official .ova file as a starting point.

I am aware of the conversion from .vmdk --> .qcow2 basically but am still struggeling with the VM Settings. I guess my problems start with having 2 vmdks to begin with.

Inspecting the converted raw images I found out that the 1.vmdk has 2 partitions (one probably the `boot` partition then second one `/`.

Regardless of this I'd wanted to try getting more wisdom from the `.ovf` file and translate this to my KVM .xml.

```
$ grep -e "Memory RAMSize" -e "CPU count" -e "Netw" -e "Disk" pks-v1.7.3-rev.1-f5289d94.ovf 
  <NetworkSection>
    <Network ovf:name="VM Network">
      <Description>VM Network</Description>
    </Network>
  </NetworkSection>
  <DiskSection>
    <Disk ovf:capacity="20" ovf:capacityAllocationUnits="byte * 2^30" ovf:diskId="system" ovf:fileRef="system.vmdk_id" ovf:format="http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized" ovf:populatedSize="4294967296" />
    <Disk ovf:capacity="20" ovf:capacityAllocationUnits="byte * 2^30" ovf:diskId="data" ovf:fileRef="data.vmdk_id" ovf:format="http://www.vmware.com/interfaces/specifications/vmdk.html#streamOptimized" ovf:populatedSize="17179869184" />
  </DiskSection>
      <Info>Networking Properties</Info>
      <Category>2. Networking Properties</Category>
        <Label>2.1. Network IP Address</Label>
        <Label>2.2. Network Netmask</Label>
        <Label>2.7. Docker Container Network Subnet</Label>
        <Label>2.8. Docker Container Network Gateway</Label>
        <rasd:Connection>VM Network</rasd:Connection>
```

(taken from [this article](http://www.binaryheartbeat.net/2016/05/importing-ova-container-into-proxmox.html)) should reveal what I need. However I can't figure out what I want really, particularly in the `<DiskSection>`

From my previous investigations I know that `disk1` is 4GiB (containing 2 partitions), while `disk2` has 12GiB. Both do not really correspond to the mentioned 20 in here. I guess it may be related to the nature of the disksize being dynamic.

Can anybody kindly advise how to translate the above output to a KVM compatible .xml/setup?

--- **Addition** ---

to make this complete ... [this is the (relevant) content](https://pastebin.com/P17U4WQR) of the .ovf file I am grepping from.

--- **Addition 2** ---

when I just convert the .vmdk into .qcow2 images, the machine shows a very short logo (Proton OS, which is the OS used here) wich then disappears into a black screen.

Comment: So I got bored and pulled down a copy of the original Photon OS 4.0 OVA to play with. Of course when I uploaded it to ESXi it worked fine. On KVM, I extracted the VMDK, converted it to qcow2, and it failed to boot just after grub with a flashing cursor. So too when I converted it to a raw image. And when I just booted straight from the VMDK, it still failed to boot. And the same after removing quiet from the boot command line. I think grub can't load the kernel or the initrd, but it's not obvious to me why.

Comment: neither importing the .ova to VirtualBox (running on a different host then mentioned KVM) works (without a real indication of the reason).

Comment: i guess I'll try to spin up a vmware instance inside a KVM machine and run the .ova from there.